# GitHub action needs to restore NuGet package from private GitHub registry

Tags: github, nuget, nuget-package, github-actions

I have a library project that I’m trying to create a GitHub action for. This action will create a NuGet package for my project but first needs to restore NuGet dependencies from both NuGet.org and a private GitHub package registry for my organization.

I need help with restoring these NuGet dependencies. Could someone point me in the right direction? A sample YAML that shows this would be great. The main challenge is to connect and restore the NuGet package from my company’s private GitHub Package registry.

Answer (score 4):

You work with private registry in the same way like with normal. The only one difference is that you need authenticate first. [Here](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages) you have in documentation.

You can use `GITHUB_TOKEN`

```
dotnet nuget add source --username USERNAME --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OWNER/index.json"
```

or `PAT`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/OWNER/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <github>
            <add key="Username" value="USERNAME" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="TOKEN" />
        </github>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Documentation says that first option works for publishing packages but it should also work for restoring.

Comment: Thank you. Here's where I'm getting stuck though. Because the NuGet package from our private registry is still a dependency, it's listed in the project file along with other NuGet dependencies. So I created two separate steps. One for restoring this private NuGet package and the second is for restoring all the other regular ones from NuGet.org. The first steps works and adds the private NuGet package but the second one fails because it's still looking for the private package on NuGet.org. Any suggestions about how to handle this?

Comment: Well because you should also have regular nuget repository. If you use dotnet command it should be done via `dotnet nuget add source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json -n nuget.org` if `nuget.config` then add this above your private `    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />`

Comment: I was doing a `dotnet restore` to add all the packages listed in project file in one step. If I understand you correctly, I need to add each NuGet package one by one in my GitHub action using `dotnet add package <PackageName>` which would allow me to specify where the package is located e.g. NuGet or my private registry. Is that correct?

Comment: No. What you need is just ensure that you have both nuget sources and if not then add official nuget source.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej, what `USERNAME` should I use when using the `GITHUB_TOKEN`? This is for an organization's package registry. Is it my username? Or is there something specific I should use?